# SQLite migration and administration

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I wanted to migrate my production MySQL database to any other RDBMS. Someone suggested me to use SQLite. I have following queries:

1. Is there any tool to migrate MySQL to SQLite?
2. Any GUI tool to manage SQLite databases?
3. How reliable it is for large production databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm not sure about the MySQL to SQLite migration tools. As always with SQL, there are SQL dialects changes that may have to be taken into account, it really depends on your existing databases.)

MySQL and SQLite are fundamentally different in that MySQL is server-based, intended to be used by a client, whereas SQLite is file-based, intended to be used via an API that accesses the underlying files directly. As such, you don't need to manage a SQLite in the same way as you would manage MySQL, because SQLite is an embedded database. There are useful tools for connecting to SQLite databases, one of them is [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817/) (it doesn't have to run within Firefox).

This may be an issue for large production databases if you need concurrent access (see [this SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5).

Answer (score 0):

Old stuff but I needed to convert a MySQL database. I have developed a small snippet in lua to do the basic job of converting the CREATE and INSERT statements. I don't guarantee that it will work in all cases. Just report if it doesn't.

And, by the way, I did the same script in GNU awk some time ago. Lua is about two times faster! As I am a big supporter of gawk that came as a surprise to me.

- Lua version: https://gist.github.com/985257
- Gawk version: https://gist.github.com/943776